# How to display string value if total SUM =0 in SSRS

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, sum

My yearly data broken down by month, and some cells  have values and some are dont. If no value then its gonna say "-". It has been achieved by simple expression

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!WP.Value),"-",Fields!WP.Value)
```

[image]

But when  I change the parameter (State) my data is much fewer. And sometimes I dont have any values for all year. So as a total I also want to display  "-". But if I use same expression for sum, it gives me an error:

```
=SUM(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!WP.Value),"-",Fields!WP.Value))
```

[image]

[image]

I tried so many different expression to find workaround but still no success. 
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the IIF() around the SUM() instead of the other way around:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(SUM(Fields!WP.Value)),"-",SUM(Fields!WP.Value))
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you sooooooo much!!! Such simple solution, I am embarrassed :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the **Number** formatting property of the text box to create the format you want.

This way, it exports correctly to Excel.[image]